# Twython : Twitter API returned 500(Internal Server Error)

Tags: twitter, twython, twitter-search

While trying to do a simple twitter search using Twython

```
twitter = Twython('..', '..','..', '..')
tweets = twitter.search(q="mangalore",count=100)
```

I am getting this error:

```
twython.exceptions.TwythonError: Twitter API returned a 500 (Internal Server Error), Internal error.
```

What might be the issue here?

Comment: 500 usually means something is broken on API side. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/error-codes-responses I am getting the same from 1 hour maybe they have some problems.

Comment: After 10 min it's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Twitter was having some issues. Working fine now.